# Serving static content via Web API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently using WebAPI running on OWIN/Katana (on a Windows Azure worker role instance). The client (homepage build with HTML, CSS & Javascript) interacts with the WebAPI via the REST interface.

Static/client related files like the HTML, CSS, Javascript, Images, ... will be saved on Windows Azure Blob Storage.

I now want to serve this static content via WebAPI/OWIN.

**First** solution was loading the file from blob storage and map a route to a controller which return the blob content of this file as `HttpResponse` (see [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1785552.aspx?Hosting%20static%20content%20in%20a%20self%20hosted%20webapi))

This works fine for just one file, but my `index.html` includes other CSS and Javascript files. So the browser starts looking @ `http://[OWIN-Web-Server-URL]/anotherJSfile.js` and of course finds nothing because there is no route defined for this. I can't/don't want to define a route for every single file, because the client should get the files from the Blob Storage without any detours over the Web Server (1-2 index/start file would be acceptable, but everything else should be served via blob storage).

**Second** attempt was to use some external library which provides a "static content"- functionality, but they all didn't work and are in alpha state (see [here](http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2013/04/27/Zero-friction-parallel-self-hosting-of-ASPNET-Web-API-and-static-files-using-OWIN-and-Katana.aspx) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220271/i-can-only-serve-one-file-with-owin-usestaticfiles)).

**Third** and not quite acceptable solution would be to redirect from `http://[OWIN-Web-Server-URL]/` to the `index.html` file on the blob storage. This way it might work, but URL would always be something like `https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/jsscripts/index.html`, which is not preferable, because if the blob storage name (xxx) would change, every link to the site would also break.

My question is:

Is there currently any solution for serving static files via Web API/OWIN? Or is there any solution in the upcoming Web API 2 release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution, that works for me:

According to my **first** solution I serve an `index.html` and a `bootstrapper.js` file via a Web API controller.

The `index.html` file will be loaded from blob storage, formatted on server (gets the storage account endpoint url: https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/) and returned via `HttpResponse` (mediatype: text/html). The `bootstrapper.js` will just be loaded and returned via `HttpResponse` (mediatype: application/javascript).

The `index.html` file now calls the `bootstrapper.js` file with the correct source URL for the remaining static content. The remaining content will be loaded relatively from the given source URL.

In our *production system* the source URL points to the blob storage, in *development enviroment* the URL points to a local web server. This is needed, **because** a HTML file served by a web server can't access files on the filesystem. Therefore a web server (we use the built in webserver in WebStorm) is needed, which provide those files.

`index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">bootstrapApp('{0}');</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

`bootstrapper.js` file:

```
/**
 * Loads all needed files asynchronously into the html file
 */
window.bootstrapApp = function(baseUrl) {
    "use strict";
    var i, assetUrls;

    window.baseUrl = baseUrl;

    assetUrls = [   'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/codemirror.min.css',
        'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.0.6/jquery.mousewheel.min.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/codemirror.min.js',
        baseUrl + '../lib/xxx.js',
        baseUrl + '../lib/xxx/xxx.js',
        baseUrl + 'resources/xxx.css',
        baseUrl + 'xxx.js'
    ];

    function endsWidth(string, suffix) {
        return (string.indexOf(suffix, string.length - suffix.length) !== -1);
    }

    // Load all assets from the previously defined array asynchronously in the order they are given in the array
    for (i = 0; i < assetUrls.length; i++) {
        // Load css or js asset
        if (endsWidth(assetUrls[i], 'css')) {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + assetUrls[i] + '" />');
        } else if (endsWidth(assetUrls[i], 'js')) {
            document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + assetUrls[i] + '"></script>');
        }
    }
};
```